# Saving search results as a "Search Folder" when they include a Task?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

In Outlook (2007), using the "Advanced Search" option, I can save the search results as a "Search Folder". For some reason, the option to save as a search folder disappears if the search results include "Task" items.

I basically want to save a search result for any "Outlook item" that has a specific category set. The same category is used on email and tasks. If the search results returns email only then I can save it but if it includes tasks I can't save it. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can only include email messages into Search Folders.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way around it or an alternative way to view both emails and tasks that have the same category set?

Comment: Only using Advanced Find with "Look Any type of Outlook item" and "Categories" set.